# How do i build a string array out of a list

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i have a function that returns a List of strings

```
static List<string> getPushIDsForCategory(string user, string project)
{
    ....
}
```

and im then using that function to build a json string on the fly

```
  var JSON = "{\"app_id\": \"MY_ID_KEY\"," +
          "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"My Message\"}," +
          "\"ios_badgeType\": \"Increase\"," +
          "\"ios_badgeCount\": \"1\"," +
          "\"include_player_ids\": [\"" + getPushIDsForCategory(user, project) + "\"]" + //<-- that string array goes here (item 1, item 2, item 3, etc...)
          "}";
```

when i run this code i get

```
{
  ...
  "include_player_ids": ["System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]"]
  ...
}
```

if I replace it with `getPushIDsForCategory(user, project)).ToArray`

i get

```
{
  ...
    "include_player_ids": ["System.String[]"]
  ...
}
```

how can i get acutal strings and not object types?

Comment: what's the code of `getPushIDsForCategory`

Comment: Why not use a Json library to create your Json object text?  FYI, just use `string.Join` to create a single string from all the values in the list.

Comment: You must add foreach loop there to print all items

Comment: This is dumb. Use JSON.NET or a similar library to make proper JSON. This code has many possible failure modes, of which you've only spotted one.

Comment: If you are creating a Json string then I'd advise using json libraries that will deal with escaping content if needed and constructing things properly. For what you want though you probably want to look at `String.Join` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to join strings together with a specified delimiter.

Comment: Don't bash OP too hard. It might be inexperience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `string.Join(", ", getPushIDsForCategory(user, project));`

This will take each object in your array and join them together with the delimiter of `", "` (comma space)

as others of mentioned, this WILL cause headache later down the line.

take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Sometimes the OP is quite obviously asking the wrong question. Should we help them down the line of a bad solution?

Comment: @spender your right, i've edited my post, but i did want to answer their question as it was asked. i think doing things the hard way is better to learn and then take the easy way out later.

Comment: `string.Join` did what I wanted but not exactly, each item was being added to a single string, I wanted each item to be a string of its own. I took your advice and using JSON.net, I was able to solve this, so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

```
static string[] getPushIDsForCategory(string user, string project)

var idsArray = String.Join(", ", getPushIDsForCategory(user, project));
"\"include_player_ids\": [\"" + idsArray + "\"]"
```

That said, you might not want to create the Json like that. What you are building there is called "a magic string". This means that if there is a problem with yout Json, you will find out at runtime rather than compile time. Rather, have a class to which you map all the data and use that to create the Json.